# Spree Existing Authentication Integration Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am currently exploring integration of the Spree Commerce engine into an existing rails application.  No issue will a standard install but attempting to use the existing devise user model failed with this error.  Perhaps the approach was wrong.  I have an app with bootstrap/devise/cancun etc.. I want to mount spree as a /store using the existing app and user model. Everything stays the same but /store is all Spree

```
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] no
What is the name of the class representing users within your application? [User] User
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] yes
 gemfile  spree
 gemfile  spree_gateway
     run  bundle install from "."
Gemfile syntax error:
...platforms => [:mri_19, :rbx]gem 'spree', '1.3.2'
...   

The Gem file is giving an error for this insert by the install routine
gem "binding_of_caller", ">= 0.7.1", :group => :development, :platforms => [:mri_19, :rbx]gem 'spree', '1.3.2'                            ^
```

Any thoughts on approach or this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Stuart, how did you get to this prompt. I am trying to do the same thing and would love to know how you accomplished this funkdified at gmail

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the spree install inserted the gem for spree on the same line.  Corrected that and ran the bundler.

Ran into a dependency error for cancan.  Spree wanted 1.6.8 so I reverted to that version.

Ran install again and it installed correctly.